# Graphics, xcolor, graphicx cannot find pdftex.def / xetex.def

Tags: graphics, pdftex, color

I have a clean install of texlive. While trying to compile any document which uses either the graphics, graphix, or the xcolor packages, I get errors that the compiler can't find the corresponding .def file.

> **pdftex.def** - if I am using pdflatex
>   **xetex.def** - if I'm using xelatex

I have downloaded the [graphics-def](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/graphics-def) package from CTAN, and copied the `.def` files to `/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics`, but I had no luck. Maybe I don't know where the files are supposed to go.

> The only thing that worked was putting the `.def` files in the same directory as my `.tex` program.

This is surely a path error. Where do I put the def files so that the packages can find them?
**EDIT:** I'm using Windows and TeXStudio. (Although I'm getting the same errors when I compile via command line)

Comment: I don't know if you're using e.g. Linux. At least with Ubuntu, you have to edit the `/etc/environment` file to add the path of TeXLive. Mine is `/usr/local/texlive/2016/bin/x86_64-linux`. It's strange, though, that you could compile a file, given what you've just said.

Comment: @JBFWP286 I'm sorry, I forgot to mention the OS. I am using Windows 8. The strange thing is, I can compile the program *when* the `.def` file is in the same directory as `myfile.tex`. So I assume I'm unable to locate the general path where the .def file should exist.

Comment: Thanks for your edit. Exactly, there are problems with your PATH. It seems you must have those files inside `C:\some-path\texlive\2016\texmf-dist\tex\latex\graphics-def`, as I don't really know the full path you installed TeXLive.

Comment: @JBFWP286 As a matter of fact, I do have those files in `..\texlive\2015\texmf-dist\tex\latex\graphics-def`

Comment: See if you can include the path to your TeXLive (`C:\texlive\2015`) in your PATH environment variable. See https://www.itechtics.com/customize-windows-environment-variables/ to know how to do so. Then, try to compile again and see if that works.

Comment: @JBFWP286 I tried that. Didn't work. Although there's already `..\texlive\2015\bin\win32` on my system path, if that helps? 
I tried putting the files in that directory too (as a hail mary).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/43117/discussion-between-jbfwp286-and-chaotictwist).

Comment: Exactly which TeX system are you using? Both MiKTeX and TeX Live releases will install these automatically.

Comment: @JosephWright I'm using TeXLive. As I mentioned in my question.

Comment: @ChaoticTwist OK, have you done `tlmgr update --self --all --reinstall-forcibly-removed` (or the equivalent from the GUI) to get all of the latest updates? Are you using TL 2016?

Comment: @JosephWright I performed a clean install from the web installer yesterday. I am using TL2015

Comment: @ChaoticTwist TL2015 didn't have the files you mention from the `graphics-def` bundle, but a complete installation will have them available. I have `tex/latex/pdftex-def/pdftex.def` and `tex/xelatex/xetex-def/xetex.def` in my TL2015 set up. What do `kpsewhich pdftex.def` and `kpsewhich xetex.def` report?

Comment: @JosephWright `kpsewhich` on both those files give me no output. I downloaded the `graphics-def` from CTAN and copied them to `tex/latex/graphics-def` folder.

Comment: It sounds like you might have a partial installation. At the command line, try `tlmgr list xetex-def` and `tlmgr list pdftex-def`. You should get a load of info with a line saying `installed:   Yes`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/43118/discussion-between-joseph-wright-and-chaotictwist).

Comment: @JosephWright Thanks for you help. It's quite strange this situation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is just for the records.

Thanks @JosephWright for your help! It was painful.

Remember to download TeXLive from a verified site: http://tug.org/texlive/acquire-netinstall.html

Here's the ISO one: https://www.tug.org/texlive/acquire-iso.html

Hope that helps!!!

Answer (score 1):

Graphics drivers were recently reorganised. For a manual installation, the contents of the `graphics-def` package has to be installed in`(texmf root)/tex/latex/graphics-def/`.

However the best solution is to use:

- TeX Live Package Manager (tlmgr) for TeX Live,
- TeX Live Utility for MacTeX,
- MiKTeX Package Manager (mpm) for MiKTeX.

Comment: I tried to compile with XeLaTeX some (old) Japanese text which once worked just fine but not with the current installation. What exactly should I do with the MiKTeX Package Manager? I get a `xetex.def` not found with `beamer`.

Comment: Ask MPM (both as admin abd as user) to install `graphics-def`.